# linux ddos attack and blocking

Tags: linux, centos, ddos

im checking ddos using this script:

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

it will show something like this

```
24 220.160.239.126
25 42.80.231.240
26 182.109.15.223
29 218.64.39.93
```

im blocking the ip using:

```
route add 218.64.39.93 reject
```

how do i combine the checking netstat with the route add reject if the count more than 20.

thanks

Comment: look at tools like fail2ban. It will add the ip address in question in iptables reject list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append:

```
|awk '$1 > 20 {print $2}'
```

to print the entry in the second column of your input when the integer in the first column exceeds the value of 20.

```
|awk '$1 > 20 {print "route add " $2 " reject"}' | /bin/sh
```

and omitting the redundant `| sort -n` would be a refinement to execute the desired command.

By the way DIY DOS protection like that is probably not the optimal solution...